# How to get quote items and description from cart2quote in header part in magento

Tags: php, magento, cart

I have installed cart2quote extension in Magento and I could not find the way to list down the items added to quote in header part. I would like to have quote items and description listed on header part from cart2quote. How could I get this?

Comment: Are you looking for the alternative of cart2quote extension? https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a 'mini cart', you should be able to copy the 'mini cart' from Magento and edit it in a way that is shows the quote products.